# Word Report replacing "block character" (□) carriage returns issue using asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I am generating word report using asp.net.
I am exporting data from the database and replacing it with the placeholders in the word document.
When i am retrieving the data from the database the string contains the "block character" (□) carriage returns which i want to eliminate? I have tried replacing it with chr(11), chr(13) but have not got any success.
for example i have the following text

abc

xyz

then the current output i am getting is as follows:

abc

□ xyz

instead of

abc

xyz
on word report.
Can you please provide me with a solution for the above issue?

Answer (score 0):

The enter can also be 0x0D (13) and following with 0x0A (10)

So replace also the chr(10) (together with your current replace of the chr(11) and chr(13)).